# Air mass model in PVLIB

Tags: python, pvlib

When running:

```
mc.run_model(tmy_data)
```

which air mass model is used?

https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/modeling-steps/1-weather-design-inputs/irradiance-and-insolation-2/air-mass/

how can I change to other air mass model?
Moreover, where can I find that information (what mathematical models are created in python and how to change it, to run the: mc.run_model(tmy_data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ModelChain documentation](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.modelchain.ModelChain.html#pvlib.modelchain.ModelChain) states:

> airmass_model (str, default 'kastenyoung1989') – Passed to location.get_airmass.